# What does AsSelf do in autofac?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

What is `AsSelf()` in autofac?
I am new to autofac, what exactly is `AsSelf` and what are the difference between the two below?

```
builder.RegisterType<SomeType>().AsSelf().As<IService>();
builder.RegisterType<SomeType>().As<IService>();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Typically you would want to inject interfaces, rather than implementations into your classes.

But let's assume you have:

```
interface IFooService { }

class FooService { }
```

Registering `builder.RegisterType<FooService>()` allows you to inject `FooService`, but you can't inject `IFooService`, even if `FooService` implements it. This is equivalent to `builder.RegisterType<FooService>().AsSelf()`.

Registering `builder.RegisterType<FooService>().As<IFooService>()` allows you to inject `IFooService`, but not `FooService` anymore - using `.As<T>` "overrides" default registration "by type" shown above.

To have the possibility to inject service both by type and interface you should add `.AsSelf()` to previous registration: `builder.RegisterType<FooService>().As<IFooService>().AsSelf()`.

If your service implements many interfaces and you want to register them all,  you can use `builder.RegisterType<SomeType>().AsImplementedInterfaces()` - this allows you to resolve your service by any interface it implements.

You have to be explicit in your registration, as Autofac does not do it automatically (because in some cases you might not want to register some interfaces).

This is also described in [here in Autofac documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/registration.html#services-vs-components)

Comment: Is not specifying either the same as specifying `AsSelf()`? I had the same question about what the purpose of AsSelf was for, but I understood what you said here already... I just am curious if it's redundant?

Comment: Never mind, I see now that if you are not registering a type as any services then there is no need to call `AsSelf()`. It's only when registering it as other services that you may want to call it.